# sql alias to dictionary returns duplicate results

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have following class

```
<class name="Product" table="Product">
<id name="ID" />
...
<map name="CustomFields" table="CustomFieldView">
     <key column="RECORDID" />
     <map-key column="CFName" type="String" />
     <element column="CFValue" type="String" />
</map>
</class>
```

and SP to select product with CustomFields dictionary

```
 <sql-query name="GetProducts">
        <return alias="p" class="Product" />
        <return-join alias="cf" property="p.CustomFields" />

        SELECT {p.*}, {cf.*}

        FROM Product p
            INNER JOIN CustomFieldView cf ON p.ID = cf.RECORDID

        // WHERE
    </sql-query>
```

when I select single product like **WHERE ID = 1234**, then it works as expected - returns one Product with populated CustomFields Dictionary property.
But when I select not single Product like **WHERE ID IN (18780, 21642) or other criterias** then I get Products duplicated 'CustomFields.Count' times, e.g. 2 Products and each has 20 Custom Fields, then 40 Products and each has 20 valid custom fields.

Do I missed something in mapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `Cartesian product` and therefore your product is being returned x times for every custom field.

To get around this problem you will need to use something like:-

```
var query = Session
    .GetNamedQuery("GetProducts")
    .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
    return query.List<Product>();
```

Please note that you will send all the data down the wire and NHibernate will perform the distinct transformer client (meaning web server or desktop app) side.

I  am not 100% sure if the return join will be populated as I have never done things this way, you will need to test this.

**edit**
I think you fetching strategy is not quite right. Do you really need a <sql-query...> Could you use another strategy e.g. `HQL`?

Comment: But such mapping works fine with e.g. <bag>, currently the issue is with <map> only. This is cumbersome for me, I'm looking for more natural solution. In any way thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I have mis-understood your question. However I think you fetching strategy is not quite right. Do you really need a `<sql-query ..` ?

Comment: You understood me quite right. Perhaps changing to HQL will help... I'll get back with test results. Thanks

Comment: I have resolved this issue with HQL. The solution is to rewrite SQL to HQL and not to use explicit 'join fetch' in HQL, just add fetch='join' to <map>. I didn't find SQL solution except using DistinctTransformer, MultiQuery and Future (not applicable with FireBird in my case). Rippo, please post HQL solution as answer, I'll check it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added note re: using a different strategy.